# How to add our own function to standard library in C++

Tags: c, function, dev-c++

I want to add my own function to the standard library in because when I want to use this function in another program. Then I can use them easily by just including the header then it can save me time and there is no need of rewriting the function again.

Comment: Don't edit the standard libraries/headers, just add your own headers, maybe in the system directories, or another one. Then from there, you can `#include` them. Editing the system headers is very bad!

Answer (score 4):

**NEVER, EVER, EVER** edit the standard library!!! Some compilers may not even use them, so if you `#include <cmath>`, it may not even use the `cmath` header, and use its knowledge about to standard library to make the math functions available. Even if it doesn't do that, it will increase the size of any other programs that use that header, even if they don't use your function.

**But I still don't want to rewrite my function!**

You don't have to. You can add your own header into the include paths of your compiler (typically `/usr/include` on *NIX), and include it like any other standard header. Or, you could save your function in a file in the directory of a file that needs it, and `#include` it like this:

`#include "my1.h"`

**Conclusion**

Don't edit the standard headers. Just add your own.